# Show Items list from a given category in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, one-to-many

I am developing a news portal with cakephp 2.4.
I have 2 tables( categories and articles)
now I want to show articles from a given category by this link: `http://mydomain/category/2`

**my category model:**

```
class Category extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Category';

var $hasMany = array('Article');
 }
```

**my article model:**

```
class Article extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Article';

var $belongsTo = Array('Category');
```

**Article controller:**

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Articles';

var $scaffold;

function lists()
 {
    $this->Article->recursive = 1;
     $myCat = $this->Category->find('all', array('order' => 'Category.id ASC'));
     return $this->Article->lists($myCat);

     }
}
```

**my category controller:**

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Categories';
var $scaffold;

function index()
  {
      $this->Category->recursive = 1;
    $this->set('showCat', $this->Category->find('all'));

  }
}
```

Now I am confused how to show the articles list by `http://mydomain/category/2`

please help me

Comment: this http://mydomain/category/2 is actually http://mydomain/category/index/2. Why dont you use new action for articles list ?

Comment: Also please tell what is the purpose of list action in ArticlesController ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I am confused how to show the articles list by /mydomain/category/2

In your categories controller

```
function index($categoryId = null) {
  $this->Category->recursive = 1;
  if ($categoryId) {
    $this->set('articles', $this->Category->Article->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Article.category_id' => $categoryId)));
  }    
}
```

Now, in you categories/index.ctp you will have $articles available.

```
<?php 
if (isset($articles)) {
  //etc etc
```

Comment: thanks Guillmo Mansilla for your nice snippet.... now I can show the articles by the given category...